# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146 table doesn't exist)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have an problem with migrations in python django. When i try to execute python manage.py makemigrations or migrate there is this error.‍♂️

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 65, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py",
>   line 101, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(query, args)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py",
>   line 250, in execute
>       self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py",
>   line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
>       raise errorvalue   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py",
>   line 247, in execute
>       res = self._query(query)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py",
>   line 412, in _query
>       rowcount = self._do_query(q)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py",
>   line 375, in _do_query
>       db.query(q)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py",
>   line 276, in query
>       _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
>   _mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'rc2.eduuser_role' doesn't exist")
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 17, in
>   
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 363, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 355, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 283, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 327, in execute
>       self.check()   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 359, in check
>       include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py",
>   line 346, in _run_checks
>       return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py",
>   line 81, in run_checks
>       new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
>   line 16, in check_url_config
>       return check_resolver(resolver)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\urls.py",
>   line 26, in check_resolver
>       return check_method()   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
>   line 254, in check
>       for pattern in self.url_patterns:   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py",
>   line 35, in **get**
>       res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
>   line 405, in url_patterns
>       patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)   File
>   "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py",
>   line 35, in **get**
>       res = instance.**dict**[self.name] = self.func(instance)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py",
>   line 398, in urlconf_module
>       return import_module(self.urlconf_name)   File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib__init__.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 994, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 678, in
>   exec_module   File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\urls.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       url(r'^eduuser/', include("eduuser.urls", namespace="eduuser")),   File
>   "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\conf\urls__init__.py",
>   line 50, in include
>       urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)   File "C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\importlib__init__.py",
>   line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 994, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 678, in
>   exec_module   File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\eduuser\urls.py",
>   line 2, in 
>       from eduuser import views   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\eduuser\views.py",
>   line 7, in 
>       from eduuser.forms import ForgotEmailForm   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\eduuser\forms.py",
>   line 107, in 
>       class ImportUserForm(forms.Form):   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\eduuser\forms.py",
>   line 123, in ImportUserForm
>       role_choices = tuple([(u'', "Auswählen")] + list([(r.id, str(r)) for r in Role.objects.all()]))   File
>   "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",
>   line 250, in **iter**
>       self._fetch_all()   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",
>   line 1118, in _fetch_all
>       self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py",
>   line 53, in **iter**
>       results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch)   File
>   "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py",
>   line 886, in execute_sql
>       raise original_exception   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py",
>   line 876, in execute_sql
>       cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 80, in execute
>       return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 65, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py",
>   line 94, in **exit**
>       six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\utils\six.py",
>   line 685, in reraise
>       raise value.with_traceback(tb)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 65, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py",
>   line 101, in execute
>       return self.cursor.execute(query, args)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py",
>   line 250, in execute
>       self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py",
>   line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
>       raise errorvalue   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py",
>   line 247, in execute
>       res = self._query(query)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py",
>   line 412, in _query
>       rowcount = self._do_query(q)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.py",
>   line 375, in _do_query
>       db.query(q)   File "C:\Source\Git\Suisseedu\resourcecenter2\ResourceCenter\ResourceCenter\env\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.py",
>   line 276, in query
>       _mysql.connection.query(self, query) django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'rc2.eduuser_role'
>   doesn't exist")

Code:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from settings import base
from eduuser.managers import EduUserManager
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
# ** AUTH USER **
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin
)

# ------------
# ROLE
# ------------
class Role(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(
        _("Role Name"),
        max_length=100,
        unique=True,
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# -------------
# EduUser
# -------------
class EduUser(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):

    objects = EduUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    first_name = models.CharField(
        _("First Name"),
        default="",
        blank=False,       
        max_length=255)

    last_name = models.CharField(
        _("Last Name"),
        default = "",
        blank=False,
        max_length=255)

    eduId = models.CharField(
        _("EduId"),
        blank=False,
        unique=True,
        db_index=True,
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that eduId already exists."),
        },
        max_length=255)

    age = models.IntegerField(
        _("Age"),
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )

    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        ('N', 'None'),
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )

    gender = models.CharField(
        _("Gender"),
        max_length=1,
        choices=GENDER_CHOICES)

    email = models.EmailField(
        _("Email"),
        max_length=255,
        unique=True,
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that email address already exists."),
        },
    )

    verify_key = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    verify_key_expires = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    email_verify = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    password_forgot_key = models.CharField(
        _("Password_Forgot_Key"),
        blank=True,
        unique=True,
        max_length=255)
    password_forgot_key_expires = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    health_info = models.TextField(
        _("Health Informations"),
        default="No Special Informations")
    special_info = models.TextField(
        _("Special Informations"),
        default="No Special Informations")
    resume_info = models.TextField(
        _("Biography"),
        default="No Bio set")

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_first_steps = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    date_of_birth = models.DateField(default="2000-01-01")
    school_start_date = models.DateField(default="2000-01-01")

    eduuser_read = models.ManyToManyField(
        base.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        related_name="eduuser_read_set",
        blank=True,
    )

    eduuser_write = models.ManyToManyField(
        base.AUTH_USER_MODEL,     
        related_name="eduuser_write_set",
        blank=True,
    )

    role = models.ManyToManyField(
        "Role",
        _("Role"),
        blank=False,
        db_index=True,
    )

    address = models.ForeignKey("country.Address",
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        default=None,
    )

    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)

    def get_full_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return "" + self.first_name + " " + self.last_name 
    def get_short_name(self):
        # The user is identified by their email address
        return self.email
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_admin
    def __str__(self):
        if self.first_name and self.last_name:
            return "" + self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
        else:
            return "" + self.email

# -------------
# Import Maching Table
# -------------

class ImportMatch(models.Model):

    role = models.OneToOneField(
        "Role",
        blank=False,
        db_index=True,
        related_name="role_host_set"
    )

    role_allowed = models.ManyToManyField(
        "Role",
        blank=False,
        db_index=True,
        related_name="allowed_role_set"
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return "" + str(self.role) + " Import Allowed Table"

# -------------
# Import Role Mapper
# -------------
class RoleMapper(models.Model):

    role = models.OneToOneField(
        "Role",
        blank=False,
        db_index=True,
    )

    role_map = models.TextField(
        _("Trennen mit Komma"),
        blank=False,
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return "" + str(self.role) + " Mapper"
```

Can somebody help me by this problem ?
Version Python: 3.6.6
Version Django: 1.11.3

**Edit:**

```
role_choices = tuple([(u'', "Auswählen")] + list([(r.id, str(r)) for r in Role.objects.all()]))
role = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.Select, choices=role_choices)
```

Comment: It sounds like something is trying to query the role table while the modules are loading (e.g. `Role.objects.all()`), but we can't tell where the problem is from the code you posted. Please include the full traceback in your question.

Comment: Also, explain if you did any changes to the database or the database settings and post the full output of the commands.

Comment: The problem is in eduuser/forms.py, where as Alasdair says you are doing a query in a class definition. It would be better to show the code of that form, but generally you should use a ModelChoiceField with a queryset rather than a ChoiceField with a set of choices queried from a model.

Comment: @DanielRoseman In Edit you can see the lines in forms. Which changes should i do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a form field with choices from a model, you should always use ModelChoiceField with a queryset.

```
role = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Role.objects.all(), empty_label="Auswählen")
```

Using static choices there not only gives you the problem you have experienced, but will also prevent the choices from updating when Role objects are added or edited. Using ModelChoiceField will do the query at the appropriate time, ensuring it is always up to date.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar error.

The reason was that I did not run migrations after adding new models.